# Taking snapshots of the webpage while unit testing using phantomjs and jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, snapshot, phantomjs

I can't seem to get communication of jasmine and phantomjs working.  I'm using the run-jasmine.js file in the examples folder for phantomjs.  The problem I get is that the file can't find system so it can't require it.

This is the specific message:

```
undefined:0 Unknown module system for require()
```

On top of that, I was wondering how to get dom manipulation of the html file working with jasmine.

EDIT: It looks like the DOM issue was simple since it's just using phantom js's headless browser functionality.  I still have the system problem, and I'm wondering how to call render page in between each test rather than when the page is done loading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the issue by following the instructions on this page

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phantomjs/Ac-77s4kFGk

Basically if you are installing phantomjs from the debian repository it is not up-to-date. Installing the latest version from their official website does the trick.